# Creating a repository and commiting multiple files with PyGithub

Tags: python, github-api, pygithub

I want to create a new empty repository and add two files to it. However, I am stuck at adding two files with a single commit.
This is my current code:

```
filename1="dummy1"
filename2="dummy2"
file1_content="something"
file2_content="something"
repo_name="dummy_repo"

repo = g.get_user().create_repo(repo_name)
repo.create_file(filename1, commit_message, file_content1)
```

The repo.create_file() takes only one file as an argument as per the docs, how do I add the second file with this commit itself?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible by combining the following `PyGithub` methods:

- `create_git_blob`
- `get_git_tree`
- `create_git_tree`
- `create_git_commit`
- `get_git_ref`
- `GitRef.edit`

A complete example is a bit long but can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ohaval/3c183c83ec91cb528fdc4628efe2fa01).

Comment: I tested today and can confirm this is the working solution. In addition, if you are looking to delete some files with git trees, set `sha=None` and it will be shown as `deleted` in the commit. Thanks @Ohav

Answer (score 0):

From my research, I don't believe it is possible to add multiple files at once to the same commit using pygithub. You would have to do this locally on a cloned copy and then push the commit to github, but I don't think that's the purpose of PyGithub.

It looks like this is a limitation of the Github API itself.